# How to trigger DataGridTextColumn edit mode from another button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I know that by double clicking the cell of a DataGrid is set to edit mode. But how can I do that from a button? The PrepareCellForEdit method of the DataGridTextColumn might be the thing I need, right? Any ideas how to do that?

```
<Grid>
<DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding StringList}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button Name="ButtonEdit">Edit</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `DataGridCell` element, set the `CurrentCell` property of the `DataGrid`, call `BeginEdit()` and then focus the `TextBox`. Here is an example for you:

```
private void ButtonEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndex = 0;

    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(MainDataGrid, MainDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ServiceAddrDataGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow, columnIndex);
    if (cell != null)
    {
        DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
        MainDataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGridCellInfo;
        MainDataGrid.BeginEdit();

        TextBox textBox = FindVisualChild<TextBox>(cell.Content as DependencyObject);
        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.Focus();
    }
}

private static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow rowContainer, int column)
{
    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        if (presenter != null)
            return presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
    }
    return null;
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information.

**How to programmatically select and focus a row or cell in a DataGrid in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks